# Chart.JS value on top disappear when tooltip show up

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have chart witch i need show up value on top each bar, and i need show tooltip too, so i try these code

```
var ctx3 = document.getElementById('canvasppicinh').getContext('2d');
                                    window.myMixedChart = new Chart(ctx3, {
                                        type: 'bar',
                                        data: chartData,
                                        options: {                                  
                                            maintainAspectRatio: false,
                                            title: {
                                                display: true,
                                                text: 'Chart KPI Financial Perfective',
                                                padding: 50
                                            },
                                            legend :{
                                                position : 'bottom'
                                            },
                                            tooltips: {
                                                mode: 'index',
                                                intersect: true,
                                                enabled: true,
                                                callbacks: {
                                                    label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                                                      var val = data.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index];
                                                      return  val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",") +',-';
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            },
                                            scales: {
                                                yAxes: [{
                                                    ticks: {
                                                        beginAtZero: true,
                                                        categoryPercentage: 1.0
                                                    },
                                                    gridLines: {
                                                        display: false
                                                    }
                                                }]
                                            },
                                            hover: {
                                                mode: false
                                            },
                                            animation: {
                                                duration : 1,
                                                onProgress: function() {
                                                    var chartInstance = this.chart,
                                                    ctx = chartInstance.ctx;

                                                    ctx.font = Chart.helpers.fontString(Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontSize, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontStyle, Chart.defaults.global.defaultFontFamily);
                                                    ctx.textAlign = 'center';
                                                    ctx.textBaseline = 'bottom';

                                                    this.data.datasets.forEach(function(dataset, i) {
                                                        var meta = chartInstance.controller.getDatasetMeta(i);
                                                        meta.data.forEach(function(bar, index) {
                                                            var data = dataset.data[index];
                                                            ctx.fillText(data, bar._model.x, bar._model.y - 5);
                                                        });
                                                    });
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });
```

Well is kinda work for me, my chart show value on top each bar but my problem is, everytime i try show tooltip value on top disappear. If tooltip disappear (not hovering) top value appearing. Did i miss something? And I have searching these problem on google, it said i need extend. But i don't have any idea how to use extend with my oldest code. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution you need plugin chartjs-plugin-datalabels, and add inside option chart

```
plugins: {
            datalabels: {
                color: 'white',
                formatter: function(value, context) {
                    return Math.round(value) + '%';
                }
            }
        }
```

And remove animation